# Could not connect in container because "The evaluation period has expired"

Tags: sql-server, docker, image

I have the following image installed on my Docker: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest`. From it I created a container, and in that container I created my database.

Today I suddenly received the following error when trying to start the container:

> Error: The evaluation period has expired.
>
> /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 104

I understand that it may be a license related problem, but I don't know how to solve it. And if it is the case that I need to update my image, is it possible to do this without losing my entire database?

I'm using Windows 11 with Docker Desktop, and I've tried running the command:

```
docker run -e MSSQL_PID=Developer 
    -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y'
    -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Gs070201!'
    -p 1433:1433 
    -d 615e05143269d67743cf44626c52eef3de5688f7e877022038f490239df3a719
```

Passing the variables indicating that I accept the EULA and that I want to use the Developer edition, so it should not have entered an evaluation period.

Comment: Presumably you were using the public preview of SQL Server 2022. It has recently been released

Comment: OMG, i am having the same issue now. Tried 2019 but still not working.

Comment: The document says the version by default is Developer : This will run the container using the Developer Edition (this is the default if no MSSQL_PID environment variable is supplied), and I assume the Developer version has no expired date.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question and not a programming question.

Comment: @KenWhite both Docker and SQL Server are "software tools commonly used by programmers" as explained in the [help/on-topic]. Voting to reopen, as this is a problem for people running said image which suddenly stops working.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Except this question isn't about **use** of a programmer's tool, it's a licensing question, which is off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. We can't address issues with licensing.

Comment: This question's closure is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421698/docker-and-sql-server-are-on-topic-and-so-is-github).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I pulled the docker image again, and it seems to fix it.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Second time visited same answer and this time also I had to struggle 2 hours before coming here :)

Comment: I am glad that it helped you again. It's interesting that this is the least technical answer on my list but has the most votes :)